# How can I convert String with comma to double in Dart?

Tags: dart, double

I have a text field in which I am taking string as input and converting it to double using double.parse() method.

I am using the number type keyboard for the textfield. But when the user inputs a comma with numbers for example 5,000 my program is giving output of 5.00

How can I get the output of 5000 from 5,000 in dart?

Comment: one way is to just ignore commas by using String replace method

Comment: try to use .toStringAsFixed(number after comma). for example: (5.000).toStringAsFixed(3); the result is 5.000

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the answer to your final question:

```
String t = '5,000';
double f = double.parse(t.replaceAll(',',''));
print(f);
```

Use `.replaceAll()` to replace all instances of the comma with no character

Answer (score 15):

You need to consider localization. Countries in Europe use comma as decimal separator while the US uses dot.

You need to use NumberFormat from intl package for the complete solution.

```
String t = '5,000';
double f = NumberFormat().parse(t);
print(f);
```

NumberFormat() automatically gets initialized with the device's current locale if you don't pass in a locale.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove "**,**" from your input string..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NumberFormat()` from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

```
double price = NumberFormat().parse(_textFieldController.text) as double;
```